# How to turn off Ubuntu One login at startup

Tags: boot

I was wondering how to turn off Ubuntu one login at boot. The thing is when my PC boots up it is asking me password, so I am providing my machine's local password and it is not accepting it until I am putting in the U.O. login password. How to turn it off?

Comment: I would suggest looking at what you have auto-start that causes the question to be asked. It's possible whatever that is, could be what you should be removing.

Comment: Aye sir checking 

Comment: It's seahorse keyring